# upload folder to ipfs using blockfrost

Tags: blockfrost, ipfs

How to upload folder to IPFS using blockfrost.

able to upload a file using the following, but not able to upload a folder

```
curl "https://ipfs.blockfrost.io/api/v0/ipfs/add" \
  -X POST \
  -H "project_id: $PROJECT_ID" \
  -F "file=@./README.md"
```

here is the full [documentation](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/IPFS-Add/paths/%7E1ipfs%7E1add/post)

any solutions?

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

You can [loop over the contents of your folder](https://askubuntu.com/a/315338) and upload every file individually using `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use `curl` to upload a folder, as it does not support multipart sending.

You might want to see something like [Using a Node.js Script to Upload a Folder to a Remote IPFS Node](https://medium.com/cladular/using-a-node-js-script-to-upload-a-folder-to-a-remote-ipfs-node-255fa9e3b766).